# Get proper output from self var python

Tags: python, oop

**What I'm trying to do:**
Output the value of a `self.out` var in a way that I can still use in another method.

**The code**

```
if self.path_object is not None:
    dictpath = {}
    for path in self.path_object:
        parsed = urlparse(path.pathToScan)
        if parsed.query:
            self.params = parsed.query.split('&', 2)
            self.out = list(map(lambda v: v.split("=")[0] +"=" + str(self.fooz), self.params))
            dictpath[parsed.geturl()] = self.out
    print dictpath
```

This code brings in a set of paths (via `path_object`), it then parses those paths on the `&` symbol and attaches the value of `self.fooz` to it, then puts it into a dictionary and outputs the results.

**Result**
Its currently outputting a list like (added spacing for readability):

```
{
u'www.somesite.com/param.php?id=317':
    u'id=[<self.fooz>, <self.fooz>, <self.fooz>,<self.fooz>, <self.fooz>, <self.fooz>]', 

u'somesite.com/param.php?id=911&param2=6&param3=cat': 
    [u'id=[<self.fooz>, <self.fooz>, <self.fooz>,<self.fooz>, <self.fooz>, <self.fooz>]', 
    u'param2=[<self.fooz>, <self.fooz>, <self.fooz>,<self.fooz>, <self.fooz>, <self.fooz>]', 
    u'param3=[<self.fooz>, <self.fooz>, <self.fooz>,<self.fooz>, <self.fooz>, <self.fooz>]']
}
```

My question is, how can I access this output in another method, so that I can loop through each parameter like:

```
u'somesite.com/param.php?id=<<<<<self.fooz>>>>>&param2=6&param3=cat':
```

then

```
u'somesite.com/param.php?id=911&param2=<<<<<self.fooz>>>>>&param3=cat
```

and then so on for each parameter in a path.

So, far I have tried requesting a url from the present output, but `requests` isn't allowing a path to be requested like `<self.fooz>` as its not a valid url (e.g. including somesite.com or http://somesite.com).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the string again. Use `urlparse.parse_qs` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html). Do it like this:

```
import urlparse
s = u'somesite.com/param.php?id=911&param2=<<<<<self.fooz>>>>>&param3=cat'
params = urlparse.parse_qs(s[s.find('?') + 1:])
print params
```

The result is:

```
{u'param3': [u'cat'], u'id': [u'911'], u'param2': [u'<<<<<self.fooz>>>>>']}
```

Now you can iterate over `params`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you show an example in this case of how to go about this?

Comment: I see how this is working now. I really appreciate it @pts ! Thanks!